# can't access shared folder of Cluster Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

I have configured a FailOver Cluster Instance (ClusterDB) with two nodes for SQL Server 2014 on Windows 2008 R2 SP 1. It's my first cluster so I'm not very sure of a lot of things, this is new for me so keep this in mind.

I created a shared folder of my backups on the cluster and successfully accessed from my Test Server (Windows Server 2012 and in the same domain). But from a few days now I can't access to this folder, when I log in into my Test Server and try to access to \ClusterDB on windows explorer, throws me an  error as it cannot find the machine.

The cluster has an internal IP and a external one for the Server and both are online, if put \InternalIP on my test server, it can connect, but this not shows the shared folder (I suppose it should be here but not sure why not).

From the nodes of the cluster (node 1 and node 2) I can connect to \ClusterDB and see the shared folder.

I checked the permissions for this folder and the main user (user which I log in on my test server) has permission to read this folder

Could anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: how you access that shared folder and get the unexpected result? by code? using some third party software/tool?

Comment: From Windows Explorer, from past friday I can't access using the Server name \\ClusterDb. But nothing changed on configuration, and the server is a production environment.

Comment: Is this folder added to the shared recourses of the cluster ?

Comment: I'm not sure the terminology of this, the folder is show on "Shared Folders" section on "FailOver Cluster Manager" on the Service for SQL Server. And until Thursday it was working ok.
This is what you mean?

Comment: i think you should move this question on serverfault. this looks like an infrastructure/server issue more than a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post and some people might get upset that I'm posting to it, however this is the result that turns up in Google when searching for an answer to this issue.

In my case the problem was the drive letter of the shared drive was removed by the failover cluster. To see this open Failover Cluster Manager, click on the File Server role, and select the resources tab at the bottom. You should see a Storage category with the drive being used listed, right click on this and select change drive letter.

The drive letter needs to either match the drive letter listed in the shares tab or you need to adjust the shares listed in the shares tab to match the new drive letter you assign to it.